# How to retrieve data from SQL Server CE with parameters

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to write a procedure that returns an image based on a parameter from a text box. I am using SQL Server CE. I have been able to figure the connection part, but I can't figure out how to properly write a parametrized command for my connection. Basically, the user enters a name on the text box and an image is returned to the picture box.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cnn As SqlCeConnection
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim strCatName As String = txtCategoryName.Text

    connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\ContactsAndInventory.sdf"
    cnn = New SqlCeConnection(connectionString)

    Dim Stream As New MemoryStream()
    cnn.Open()

    ***Dim command As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT IMAGE FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORY WHERE (CATEGORY_NAME = @CATEGORY_NAME)", cnn) 'Here is my issue***

    Dim image As Byte() = CType(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    Stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
    cnn.Close()
    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(Stream)

    picCategoryImage.Image = bitmap

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.

```
Dim command As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT IMAGE FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORY WHERE (CATEGORY_NAME = @CATEGORY_NAME)", cnn)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY_NAME", myTextBox.Text)
```

or:

```
Dim command As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT IMAGE FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORY WHERE (CATEGORY_NAME = @CATEGORY_NAME)", cnn)

command.Parameters.Add("@CATEGORY_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = myTextBox.Text
```